# url issues, need to redirect 3 urls but the codes i've tried arent working

Tags: apache, redirect, canonical-link

I know nothing about code sadly but i'm hoping that you can help. I've tried asking my web designer but he claims he doesn't know what a 301 redirect is and have noticed his own site has canonicalization issues.

I need to redirect the 3 urls below to www.mydomain.co.uk

- www.mydomain.co.uk/index.html
- mydomain.co.uk/index.html
- mydomain.co.uk

I have never used ftp before, but have downloaded filezilla tonight so i can try fix this and have made a .htaccess file as my site didnt seem to have one.

I have browsed (almost) the whole internet looking for answers to this solution and have tried some codes suggested in previous posts on here but they didn't seem to do anything.

If you need to know, i think my server is apache.

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope your site isn't built using HTML..  However, using your `.htaccess` you could try:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.co\.uk [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
   ```

This should be sufficient enough to force the www  If you need to force the index.html you would do:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.co\.uk [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's been a while, but both of these should sufficient to do what you want...

1. I think it's time to find a new developer, because the one you have sounds like a complete idiot.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying but putting these into the .htaccess files didn't do anything for me and there are still 4 versions of the website.

Comment: Your server might not have mod_rewrite turned on, which would make .htaccess hacks fail every time.  if you create a file named info.php and in it put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and upload it then run it in the browser, it will have a lot of stuff in there but you'll be able to find and see if mod_rewrite is turned on or not.